# Anyone knows where is "start in background" permission in MIUI 11?

Tags: android, android-permissions, miui

I'm not able to start activity in MIUI 11 redmi note 6 pro mobile, I am getting error as:

> com.android.server.am.ExtraActivityManagerService: MIUILOG- Permission Denied Activity

I found some solution like turn on "start in background" permission. I can't find something like this with MIUI 11. Literally I have no idea about this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17):

I have a similar problem with starting activity from BroadcastReceiver when application is stopped.
 
**1)** You can find your app in the settings and allow permission *"start in the background"*.
**2)** If you need to allow permission programmatically, try to open application settings

### Xiaomi

This code will open **applicatin permissions settings** in which you should allow *"start in the background"*

```
Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter",
"com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
startActivity(intent);
```

### Devices without system wrappers

This code will open the **applicatin settings** in which you should open permissions and allow *"start in the background"* permission

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Read more about android settings intents:
[How to open application permission window in app settings programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35456767/how-to-open-application-permission-window-in-app-settings-programmatically/35456817)

And you can also **check the code from github** to work with permissions in different system wrappers like flyme, miui, oppo etc:
https://github.com/zhaozepeng/FloatWindowPermission

## Hope this helps you!

#### If you have other options for resolving this issue, I would appreciate a reply in the comments . . .

Comment: Solution is good. Is there any way to grant that permission programatically? I've seen that Facebook did it. Because When I Install app it by default on permission in Facebook app.

Comment: @BhavinChauhan such apps like Facebook have more privileges by default. Google's policy forces developers to request permissions at runtime with default tools, where the permission of other system wrappers like MIUI is not usually provided. 

We must describe the intentions of using the function for which we are requesting permission in the dialog and direct the user to the settings. It is also good practice to close the application or limit some of its features if the user has declined the permission offer.

Comment: @BhavinChauhan In my application (alarm clock) I used device admin and notifications.

check here how to implement device admin -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672404/lock-android-phone 

or read more about device admin here -> https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminReceiver

So, I lock screen in my broadcast receiver and then show notification.

See my code snippet here -> https://github.com/lincollincol/AlarmClock-for-programmers/blob/master/app/src/main/java/linc/com/alarmclockforprogrammers/infrastructure/service/AlarmReceiver.java

Comment: @BhavinChauhan This is not the best practice, but this is another method of solving the problem WITHOUT PERMISSION.

Comment: @BhavinChauhan is there any way to know is permission granted or not?

Comment: Because we should not ask for permission if user already grant permission

Comment: @RajGohel Sorry I don't know how to check that permission

Comment: @lincollincol - thank you for this - is there a way in code to heck if the permission is already granted, to open open the dialog if needed?