# Xiaomi devices permission to enable apps pop-up windows while running in the background

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

Xiaomi devices latest update introduced a new permission that prevents my app (custom shortcuts launcher) that works in the background from working untill users enable this permission:
""Display pop-up windows while running in the background"

The question is, how can I show a permission prompt window for this permission, or at least how to redirect users to "other permissions" screen?

Comment: Same question, would love to see an answer.

Comment: Did you find any solution and can you please form which android version this behavior changed or miui version?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To redirect users to the "other permissions" screen use this code

```
        Intent intent = new Intent("miui.intent.action.APP_PERM_EDITOR");
        intent.setClassName("com.miui.securitycenter",
                "com.miui.permcenter.permissions.PermissionsEditorActivity");
        intent.putExtra("extra_pkgname", getPackageName());
        startActivity(intent);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59380516/2630035)

Still looking for a way to tell if this option is checked or not programmatically...

What's more interesting is, how some apps have managed to have this option checked before any user interaction... maybe there is some secret miui permission?...

Comment: Good question. I'm still looking for a way to check if the permission was granted

Comment: @NatanLotério are you get any solution for check permission is granted or not because i  am also looking for this solution

Comment: Hi @RajGohel sorry for the late response. No, we didn't find a good way to do this. So we are asking the user to check it manually.

Comment: @NatanLotério But have you find a way to check user give manually permission or not because if user give permission manually second time we should not ask user to give permission right?

Comment: I have also open dialog where user can click and move  to permission screen  and enable permission but dialog open every time how you check user give permission or not

Comment: No, we check if the SO is MIUI so then, we show the settings screen sending an intent for 'ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS' . 
The user must verify if the permission was granted by himself.

Comment: Any luck of finding a way to check if this permission enabled?

Answer (score 0):

This permission is added automatically by Google Play and isn't granted on local builds, not even release builds

if you target SDK version 30 and compile with 30, Google Play will give you the permission

```
   compileSdkVersion 30
   targetSdkVersion 30
```

note: I targeted 28 and it didn't work for me