# Activity doesn't open when app is in background in Xiaomi devices

Tags: android, background-service, xiaomi

> When app is in background,Service is running fine  but activity is not opening while app is in foreground the everything working fine. Service is able to open the activity.

**When I allow the permission of "Start in background" then code is working fine.**

> Is there any by default i can enable the "Start in background" permission.
>
> Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: this is issues is described and can be solved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59418504/xiaomi-devices-permission-to-enable-apps-pop-up-windows-while-running-in-the-bac/65172936#65172936